# Active record callbacks. How are they able to access variables/scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm hung up on using Active Record callbacks. I know how to *use* them, but I'm trying to truly *understand* what is happening, and I'm not getting it. My confusion has to do with variable scopes in Ruby.

Here is a simple Active Record class for a user with fields: email, password_hash, password_salt

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :password
    before_save :encrypt_password

    #validation
    validates :password, :confirmation => true
    validates :email, :password, :presence => true
    validates :email, :uniqueness => true

    #When saving the user, encrypt the password
    def encrypt_password

        #First check if the password is present
        if (password.present?)

            #encrypt the password
            self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
        end

    end

end
```

In the method "encrypt_password", how is the variable "password" accessible? Is it the same as self.password (object var?), and is this not the same as @password? (why?)

In the actual encryption routine, I invoke self.password_salt. I noticed that I can simply type in "password_salt" (without reference to self) and it doesn't work. Why not? Why is this different from @password_salt?

Sorry if this comes across as noobish, I've spent a good couple of hours bashing away at this, and I'm struggling to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It is the same as `self.password`. ActiveRecord defines methods, not instance variables to access stuff related to the database. That's why you cannot access it with `@password`.

2) You need to use `self.password_salt=` because otherwise you'd be assigning a local variable, not doing a method call.

PS: Callbacks are only method calls on your object. The only difference is that Rails calls them for you, not yourself.