# Why can't I directly access instance variables in Active Record callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, instance-variables

In Active Record callbacks, I always see [examples](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) using `self.variable`. Sometimes, the `self.` prefix isn't needed, so they use just `variable` (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496380/why-do-activerecord-callbacks-require-instance-variables-or-instance-methods-to)).

From what I've read, these two methods of referencing the class instance variable are using the accessor function, whereas `@variable` would directly access the variable. In my code, I tried to use `@variable` and it didn't work - it was as if `@variable` was not defined yet... can you not access instance variables directly in an Active Record callback?

Also, I haven't defined an accessor function for this particular variable, so what actually happens when I say `self.variable` or `variable` (I've tried both, and both work aside from the LHS of an assignment)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648064/active-record-callbacks-how-are-they-able-to-access-variables-scope) is essentially what I am asking, but I don't understand the answer and want more clarification (I can't comment on the answer because I'm new to Stack Overflow). His answer is this:

> It [password] is the same as self.password. ActiveRecord defines methods, not instance variables to access stuff related to the database. That's why you cannot access it with @password.

But the callback methods I've seen are always defined in the model's class, which should give them access to instance variables, right? He also says this:

> PS: Callbacks are only method calls on your object. The only difference is that Rails calls them for you, not yourself.

So does he maybe mean that the callback methods aren't call from a reference to the object? E.g. rather than calling as `model_instance.callback_method`, it is just called as `callback_method`? How would callback_method be found without a reference to an instance of the class if it is a class instance method? And even if it did work this way, how would it know what `self.variable` was?

Comment: How are you defining the callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you not access instance variables directly in an Active Record callback?

You *can* access instance variables from any instance method, including those used as ActiveRecord callbacks.

> Also, I haven't defined an accessor function for this particular variable, so what actually happens when I say self.variable or variable (I've tried both, and both work aside from the LHS of an assignment)?

First, it is important to know what the difference between the two syntaxes. `variable = 123` will assign the value `123` to a local variable. `self.variable = 123` will call a method named `variable=` on self and pass `123` as an argument.

```
> class Foo
>   def x=(value)
>     puts "Foo#x called with #{ value }"
>   end
>
>   def bar
>     x = 123       # local variable assignment, `x` only exists inside the `bar` method.
>     self.x = 456  # calls `x=` 
>   end
> end

> Foo.new.bar
Foo#x called with 456
```

Something that can be a bit confusing is that methods invoked with an implicit receiver shares the same syntax with referencing a local variable.

```
> class Bar
>   def x
>     "In method x"
>   end
>
>   def foo
>     # No local variable `x` has been initialized yet, so references to `x` will call the method with that name.
>     puts x           # calls method `x` and prints "In method x".
>                      # This example is equivalent to `puts self.x`.
>
>     x = "Hello"      # Now that a local variable is defined it will hide the method `x`.
>     puts x           # references the local variable and prints "Hello".
>     puts self.x      # calls the method `x` and prints "In method x".
>   end
> end

> Bar.new.foo
In method x
Hello
In method x
```

Second, you need to know that ActiveRecord creates accessor methods for each column of your model's table. Let's say that I have a model `User(id: integer, name: string, age: integer)`. ActiveRecord will define *instance methods* `id`, `name` and `age` to read the attributes and  `id=`, `name=` and `age=` to set the attributes.

*Instance variables* are something else entirely. You *cannot* access the database attributes with instance variables like `@id`, `@name`, `@age`.

> So does he maybe mean that the callback methods aren't call from a reference to the object?

No, ActiveRecord callbacks do indeed invoke instance methods on the object.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! I also just found [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/), which basically said the same thing you did. There they say that you can access the actual variable via `self[:variable] = value` and that this wraps the write_attribute and read_attribute - does that mean you always have to go through the Rails defined accessors? When would you use `self[:variable]` instead of `self.variable`?

Comment: I have found that most developers use `self.variable` over `self[:variable]`. The methods are equivalent, though, and can be interchanged except in cases like those mentioned in the article, which revolve around overriding the attribute method. In general I would recommend to avoid defining methods in your models which have the same name as a database column (that often causes confusion). It is good to be aware that `self[:variable]`, `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` are available, just in case you need them.

Comment: `self[:variable]` may also be used as a convenience if the attribute name you are using was generated dynamically.  e.g. `attr_name = first_name? ? :first_name : :last_name`  `self[attr_name]  # Returns either first_name or last_name`

Comment: `self[:variable]` can be used if you override getter method, so you get value and don't get infinite loop error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't quite understand that Rails attributes are not stored within instance variables. All your attributes (defined by the database table schema) are stored in one instance variable `@attributes`, which is intended to be never accessed directly, as it is a part of the Rails implementation details.

Example:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assume that we have a 'name' column in the database

  def foo
    # correct ways to access the name
    name
    self.name
    self[:name]

    # this contains name value and other name metadata
    # but you shouldn't use it
    @attributes[:name]

    # this holds nil as that variable has no relation to the "name" attribute
    @name
  end
end
```

In callbacks it works the same way as within all the other methods — you can access the instance variables defined by you, but you can't access database attributes as instance variables.

```
 class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :secret

  after_initialize do
    @secret = '123'
  end

  before_create do
    p @secret
  end

  after_validation :on_validation
  def on_validation
    p @secret
  end
end
```

If you try to create a `Thing` object both the block-based `before_create` callback and the method-based `after_validation` callbacks can access the instance variable `@secret` defined in the `after_initialize` callback.