# Rails: :save returns NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, post

I am programming a small rails api for practice. The goal is to POST some data and then save it (after further processing) in a database. The object is being created successfuly. On the save method appears an error which I cannot explain:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/api/v1/calculations_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

It appears in the :create method (on POST):

```
  # POST /calculations
  def create
    @calculation = Calculation.new(calculation_params)
    if @calculation.save # <- This is line 19
      render json: @calculation, status: :created, location: @calculation
    else
      render json: @calculation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The model looks like this:

```
require 'digest'

class Calculation < ApplicationRecord

  attr_reader :value, :hash_value, :algorithm, :timestamp
  @@known_algorithms = ['SHA2_256', 'SHA2_384', 'SHA2_512']

  def initialize (params)
    @value = params[:value]
    @algorithm = params[:algorithm]
    validate!
    @hash_value, @timestamp = digest
  end

  private

  def digest
    case @algorithm
    when 'SHA2_256'
      result = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(@value)
    when 'SHA2_384'
      result = Digest::SHA2.new(384).hexdigest(@value)
    when 'SHA2_512'
      result = Digest::SHA2.new(512).hexdigest(@value)
    end
    return result, DateTime.now
  end

  def validate!
    raise ArgumentError.new('Value cannot be empty or NIL!') if @value.nil? or @value.empty?
    raise ArgumentError.new('Unknown hashing algorithm!') unless @@known_algorithms.include? @algorithm
  end
end
```

Why does the `NoMethodError` appear? Did I override some important part in the model class?

Full stack trace as requested:

```
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:424:in `clear_transaction_record_state'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309:in `save'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
/home/pbz/RubymineProjects/hasher_api/app/controllers/api/v1/calculations_controller.rb:20:in `create'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/home/pbz/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
/home/pbz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/home/pbz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
/home/pbz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/home/pbz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
/home/pbz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you please check if you're getting valid data in `calculation_params` ?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @mehedi I get valid params. When accessing and printing the members of the calculation object I get correct values.

Comment: @engineersmnky updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override `initialize` in the `AR`. It could possibly break a lot of stuff in your models.

You can use [`after_initialize`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find).

> The `after_initialize` callback will be called whenever an Active Record
>   object is instantiated, either by **directly using new or when a record
>   is loaded from the database.** It can be useful to avoid the need to
>   directly override your Active Record `initialize` method.

```
def after_initialize
  # Gets called right after Calculation.new
  # Do some stuff here
end
```

If you still want to use `initialize` you must do something like this:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  super
  self.attributes = attributes
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I found out more about how ActiveRecords [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682931/9926929) and how to access the fields of it. Together with after_initialize everything works fine. I will now post my own answer and accept it. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @PhilippB upvote is the best _thank you_ you can say.

Comment: I upvoted, but since I'm low on repution it's not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I did find out (thanks to @Зелёный), that to create values for the model after creating it (`new`) I need to use the `after_initialize` callback Rails provides. Together with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682931/9926929) on how to access model instance variables, I was able to achieve the functionality I wanted. 
The original NoMethodError was a result of my incorrect use of the `initialize` method. The following code is the final result, which works with the default controller.

```
require 'digest'

class Calculation < ApplicationRecord

  @@known_algorithms = ['SHA2_256', 'SHA2_384', 'SHA2_512']

  after_initialize :init

  private

  def init
    validate!
    calculate!
  end

  def calculate!
    self.hash_value, self.timestamp = digest
  end

  def digest
    case algorithm
    when 'SHA2_256'
      result = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(value)
    when 'SHA2_384'
      result = Digest::SHA2.new(384).hexdigest(value)
    when 'SHA2_512'
      result = Digest::SHA2.new(512).hexdigest(value)
    end
    return result, DateTime.now
  end

  def validate!
    raise ArgumentError.new('Value cannot be empty or NIL!') if value.nil? or value.empty?
    raise ArgumentError.new('Unknown hashing algorithm!') unless @@known_algorithms.include? algorithm
  end
end
```